# Store value into two dimension get error in nested loop

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm

C Program

```
#define FRAME_WIDTH     640
#define FRAME_HEIGHT    480
void draw( int cX, int cY, int width, int height, int16_t (*frame)[FRAME_WIDTH] ) {
    int16_t color;
    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {

            color = i&0xff; 
            frame[y][x] = color; // assembly code error

        }
    }
}

int main() {
  int16_t frame[FRAME_HEIGHT][FRAME_WIDTH]; 
  draw( cX, cY, FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT, frame );
} // main()
```

Here is my Assembly Code in draw function.

```
       .data
color: .word 0
       ...
       ldr r12,=color
       str r10,[r12]      @store i&0xff into color
       ldr r8,[sp,#0]     @get int16_t (*frame)[FRAME_WIDTH]
       mul r8,r8,r6       @ y is stored in r6
       mov r9,r5,lsl #1   @ x is stored in r5
       ldrh r12,=color
       ldrh r12,[r12]
       strh r12,[r8,r9]   @frame[y][x] = color;
```

I'm new to ARM, and I encountered an error while practicing.

It displays `segmentation fault`, then I use debugger to see that there is an error in the two-dimensional array.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Do not make alt accounts to get around question bans!  [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65453732/417501) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't understand where exactly the value `frame` is stored:

> ```
> ldr r8,[sp,#0]     @get int16_t (*frame)[FRAME_WIDTH]
> ```

However, the following combination of instructions definitely makes no sense:

> ```
> mul r8,r8,r6       @ y is stored in r6
> mov r9,r5,lsl #1   @ x is stored in r5
> ...
> strh r12,[r8,r9]   @frame[y][x] = color;
> ```

Why?

This piece of code will cause the `strh` instruction to store some data to the memory location (address) `r8*r6+2*r5` (while the value of `r8` *before* the `mul` instruction is meant).

However, the address of `frame` can change when running the program multiple times, of course.

If the address of `frame` changes by some offset `n`, then the address `strh` writes to shall also change by `n`.

In other words: If `frame` is `0x1000` when running the program the first time and it is `0x1100` when running the program the second time, the value of `r8*r6+2*r5` must also change by `0x100` (assuming your code works correctly).

This is obviously not the case!

What you are doing here is *multiplying the pointer*:

```
*(int16_t *)((y*(int)frame) + 2*x)=color;
```

However, what you want to do is:

```
*(((int16_t *)frame) + FRAME_WIDTH*y + x)=color;
```

... which is the same as:

```
*(int16_t)(((int8_t *)frame) + 2*FRAME_WIDTH*y + 2*x)=color;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand how to do ```frame```.

Comment: @Kias If you are sure that `r8` contains `frame` (unfortunately, I don't know this!), you have to calculate `2*(FRAME_WIDTH*y+x)` (and not the value `2*x`) in the register `r9` and then perform the operation `strh r12, [r8, r9]`.

Comment: I use ```ldr r8, [sp,#4]``` to get ```frame```, and then it works !!! Thank you so much.